# GZcompress and Base64 encode script without deleting any line breaks

Tags: php

I've attempted multiple scripts to get this working. I want to base64_encode(gzcompress( my PHP file so all contents becomes obfuscated without affecting the original contents however everytime I run my script;

```
<?php
$script = base64_encode(gzcompress(file_get_contents('script.php')));
file_put_contents('string.txt', $script);
?>
```

I get outputted a string that when reversed PHP code inside automatically reverts to a single line and I assume the PHP code is broken since it no longer works.

Just confirmed, base64 side works fine so it seems to be an issue with the gz compression.

Comment: Where's the code that you use for reversing?

Comment: Try without the str_reverse.

Comment: For reversing I use:

    `<?php
    $script = gzuncompress(base64_decode('string'));
    file_put_contents('script.txt', $script);
    ?>`

and that outputs the script on a single line.

Comment: different host OS's, e.g. trashing on unix, untrashing on windows?

Comment: probably `\r\n` and `\n\r` miracles